# Animation fails to resume through switching tabs

Tags: iphone, animation

I've seen a bunch of similar questions on here, but none of them had what I was looking for.
Anyways:

I'm animating an Annotation on a map to move up and down. I do this by calling this function in its drawRect:

```
    - (void) wiggle {
      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.45 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
          [self.subView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.subView.frame.origin.x, self.subView.frame.origin.y+WIGGLE_DISTANCE, self.subView.frame.size.width, self.subView.frame.size.height)];
      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished)
          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.45 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            [self.subView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.subView.frame.origin.x, self.subView.frame.origin.y-WIGGLE_DISTANCE, self.subView.frame.size.width, self.subView.frame.size.height)];
          } completion:^(BOOL finished) {if (finished) [self wiggle]; }];
      }];
    }
```

In short, it's animating a 'subView' up, and when that finishes, animating down, and when that finishes, calls itself (to continue wiggling).

This works fine until I switch tabs. When I return to this tab, there is no animation. I've tried calling 'setNeedsDisplay' on each of these views in the viewController's 'viewDidAppear', and that fails to call drawRect. So then I tried just calling 'wiggle' directly from the viewController's 'viewDidAppear', and the function DOES get called, but it just doesn't animate. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can move an annotation. Try using the wiggle on another UI element (button, image, textview) and see if that works?